# Edit an html page like the concept of WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, content-management-system, wysiwyg

I would like to give The admin:

- The ability to edit parts in an html page lively by chnaging the view to something like WYSIWYG.
- After submit, the entire content must change

Something similar to the edit mode in DRUPAL:
Image: http://s9.postimg.org/lp1rnaqgv/Capture.jpg

Is there any plugin or ideas?

Comment: You would need some authentication method, what server side scripting are you using?

Comment: From close reason: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: mediawiki http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki is nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContentEditable is your answer. This will allow the user to change the dom and when he submits it will store to the database. But if you need styling and the admin is not a coder, I suggest you go with a editor like tinymce.

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: What shall i do after the submit ? take the entire page and save it in the same php file? for example!!

Comment: You will need a database to store that part and this content will always need to be fetched from the database. or else you have to directly write to the file which is not recommended.